# How to secure solr 6 admin page

Tags: solr

Installed Solr6.1 on Ubuntu14 and imported data from MySql table. Can somebody guide me how to secure mydomain/ip:8983/solr from public.

I tried instructions given on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Basic+Authentication+Plugin but zookeepr connection failed while adding security.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all go to your `webdefault.xml` present in `etc` directory . Put follwing lines in your web.xml .

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>samplerealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

 <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

In `etc` folder, create a `samplerealm.txt` file and add follwing content to that file `user1: user1pass,user` . Here user1 is your username and user1pass is the password , for the role `user` which you just defined in `web.xml`. After that go to `jetty.xml` file in your `etc` folder and look for following line `<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">` Just below this line paste the following code :

```
  <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
        <Set name="name">samplerealm</Set>
        <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/samplerealm.txt</Set>
        <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
```

After that , stop and restart your Solr server . When you visit solr page now, it will ask you for credentials . Provide user1 as your username and user1pass as password , as declared in your sample realm.txt file . Later on, you can change the password as you wish . This is how you do a http basic authentication in Solr . It works 100% . Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Yay !! :) happy to help .

Comment: I don't understand if I must update web.xml or webdefault.xml. In webdefault.xml there is already   <security-constraint> it is necesssary to delete it?

Comment: @Alessandra , you must update webdefault.xml . You do not need to delete the already present <security-constraint> tag , but just paste whatever the content , you are seeing inside the security constraints tag here . Let me know if that helps you .

Comment: @multi10ant I followed the same. For some reason, I enter the credentials, the prompt appears again for username and password. Seems like , it takes the credentials , seems like it loads but, it doesnt . No error as well

Comment: This won't work for SolrCloud as there's no way to provide credentials to Solr node (it needs to get access to admin area).

Comment: I found an issue when adding the `<Call name="addBean">` as the first line under the <Configure> section. Moving it to the bottom of the <Configure> section (before </Configure>) fixed the issue

Comment: I got same problem as @upagna got, it ask credentials again and again though i had entered right creds.

Comment: @upagna do you get solution? I also get auth popup every time even with right credentials.

Comment: @All got solution for prompt appear again and again.
Credentials should not in /etc/realm.properties
It should place in solr file, something like this /opt/solr-6.6.2/server/etc/realm.properties

Answer (score 0):

You could enable SSL. I'm not sure whether that's the desired security - you'll have to provide more info.

With SSL are you atleast able to encrypt communication between the SolrCloud and clients, along with the inter-Solr-node-communication.

Link for enabling SSL: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL

Comment: Do not have SSL, can not we do it without SSL