# Apache SOLR change admin password

Tags: apache, solr, passwords

I have installed apache solr on my machine. During the installation I set up a password, which I need to change now. I have found `apache-solr\conf\password` file, where hash is stored, but I don't know how I can change password. 
Solr version is 6.1.0-2

Comment: You should specify which version of Solr

Comment: @freedev it is 6.1.0-2 , the question has been updated

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314875/jetty-solr-admin-panel-password

Answer (score -1):

Remove default authentication and implement your own . First of all , delete everything from `solr.conf` in `conf` folder except these lines

```
 ProxyPass /solr http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr
ProxyPassReverse /solr http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr
```

Also delete `password` file . Now the default authentication is removed , and you can implement your own basic authentication in Solr , using these steps from my answer given here [How to secure solr 6 admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721049/how-to-secure-solr-6-admin-page/38729593#38729593) . This will definitely work as it is applicable to solr 6 .